# Do posthumous Booyahs power up a Booyah Bomb?

Tags: splatoon-3

The Booyah Bomb gets powered up by receiving Booyahs from your team. Interestingly, you can still send Booyahs while you're waiting to respawn after getting splatted.

If a teammate uses a Booyah Bomb and I send them Booyahs while waiting to respawn, will my posthumous Booyahs power it up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the answer is yes, It will power it up. I powered it up after I died and it worked. I'm pretty sure as long as it lets you do it it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).